# Extracting a column from a vcf file

Tags: vcf, snp, wes

I have a zipped vcf file of dbSNP hg38 version

No space left on my device to unzip that

I want to extract a column from that

I have tried this

```
cut -f 3 00-All.vcf.gz | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > cols.csv
```

But that needs my vcf to be unzipped

Do you know any solution please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the `zcat` command or `gunzip -c` will decompress the file in a streaming fashion to the standard output without writing the decompressed data to disk. Pipe the output to `cut`, `sed`, etc.

Try

```
zcat 00-All.vcf.gz | cut -f 3 | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > cols.csv
```

or

```
gunzip -c 00-All.vcf.gz | cut -f 3 | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > cols.csv
```

But if you just want a single 'column' (I presume you mean field), then you are better off just doing `bcftools query`.

Comment: On some systems I have issues with `zcat` but `gunzip -c` will also accomplish the same result.

Comment: @Exhausted Don't use unix utilities for this - it needs a level of expertise that your post history suggests you do not have. Use bcftools instead, that will address a lot of edge cases that you can't foresee.

Comment: tar can do select zip file search and extraction, but you're also data munging.

Comment: Thank you all, but why you down voting me?

Comment: I have No idea, I didn’t downvote.